# How to replace this C# code by XAML tags?

Tags: wpf, styles, tabcontrol

I have the following C# code in WPF application.

```
Style s = new Style();
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed));
this.ItemContainerStyle = s;
```

The `this` is reference to `System.Windows.Controls.TabControl` object.
Can anyone help me to write this code by using XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="VisibilityCollapsed">
      <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource VisibilityCollapsed}">
   ......
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Should be something like:

```
<Style>
    <Setter Property="Visbility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="VisibilityCollapsed" x:Type="TabItem">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource VisibilityCollapsed}">
...
</TabControl>
```

[See also MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: did not work because of two reason.
1 - there is not "TargetType" for the style. and this produce compile time error.
2 - If we but TargetType="TabControl" of this style.
 this XAML code will hide the TabControl itself, which I do not want.